# Getting part of R object from python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I can get the output I need using R, but I can not reproduce within python's rpy2 module.

In R:

```
> wilcox.test(c(1,2,3), c(100,200,300), alternative = "less")$p.value
```

gives

```
[1] 0.05
```

In python:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
rwilcox = robjects.r['wilcox.test']
x = robjects.IntVector([1,2,3,])
y = robjects.IntVector([100,200,300])
z = rwilcox(x,y, alternative = "less")
print z
```

gives:

```
Wilcoxon rank sum test  
data:  1:3 and c(100L, 200L, 300L)  
W = 0, p-value = 0.05  
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is less than 0
```

And:

```
z1 = z.rx('p.value')
print z1
```

gives:

```
$p.value  
[1] 0.05
```

Still trying to get a final value of 0.05 stored as a variable, but this seems to be closer to a final answer.

I am unable to figure out what my python code needs to be to to store the p.value in a new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using list() ?

```
pval = z.rx2('p-value')
print list(pval) # [0.05]
```

rpy2 also works well with numpy:

```
import numpy
pval = numpy.array(pval)
print pval       # array([ 0.05])
```

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/numpy.html#from-rpy2-to-numpy

Comment: Thanks, this is actually something i had been trying, but keeps resulting in "Segmentation fault: 11" crashes. Trying to grab 'method' is working correctly though so i guess this is something wrong with my computer.

Comment: @ded: This is most likely incompatible compiled libraries between R and rpy2. This can happen when upgrading R without reinstalling rpy2 (mostly on recent OS X if I rely on reports from users). If the segfault persists, please file a bug (with code to trigger it) on the bitbucket page for rpy2.

Answer (score 3):

`z1` is a `ListVector` containing one `FloatVector` with one element:

```
>>> z1
<ListVector - Python:0x4173368 / R:0x36fa648>
[FloatVector]
  p.value: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector'>
  <FloatVector - Python:0x4173290 / R:0x35e6b38>
[0.050000]
```

You can extract the float itself with `z1[0][0]` or just `float(z1[0])`:

```
>>> z1[0][0]
0.05
>>> type(z1[0][0])
<type 'float'>
>>> float(z1[0])
0.05
```

In general you are going to have an easier time figuring out what is going on in an interactive session if you just supply the name of the object you want a representation of. Using `print x` statement transforms things through `str(x)` when the `repr(x)` representation used implicitly by the interactive loop is much more helpful. If you are doing things in a script, use `print repr(x)` instead.

Comment: the suggestion of repr is most appreciated, it wasn't something i was familiar with. As noted in my comment to muraveill, this works, but likewise is giving me "Segmentation fault: 11" crashes